# How to layout items in winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, layout

I am working on a homework c# winforms project and would like to add date and time in top right corner of my main form in a way that in first row I have a date written in one label, and on second row I have time written in second label. 
Also I need that those stick in the top right corner if form is resized.

I don't know if it matters, but those label controls are inside panel which is top docked in form, and this panel already contains two controls that are docked left.

[example of what I want](https://ibb.co/cY9yBPM)

I've been playing with anchor and dock properties but I can't get it to work in a way I want.

```
private void GlavnaForma_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerDateTime.Start();
    lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd.M.yyyy", new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
}

private void timerDateTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd.M.yyyy", new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("hr-HR"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the anchor to Top, Right like so:

[image]

Comment: Also, he'd probably want to set text 'RightToLeft` property to true.

Comment: William, thanks for answer, but if I do that for both of the controls I get this:
https://ibb.co/SX8gRnn

Comment: "RightToLeft" property setting to true also doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Try setting TextAlign to MiddleRight and AutoSize to false.  Then resize the label to as big as you'd like.

Comment: I managed to get first row as wanted by setting TextAlign property to "MiddleRight" and Dock property to "Right"... now it's displaying as it should.
How to get second row docked right but below the first row?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

I would probably make the main form have a table layout panel with one column and three rows. Make the top two rows be absolutely sized and the third row have size type "percent" with a value of 100.0% to take up all remaining room. Then put a label each in the top two rows and justify the labels to the right via setting their "Dock" property to "Right".

All of this can be done in the form designer GUI. The generated code looks like the following:

```
this.tableLayout = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
this.labelDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.labelTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.tableLayout.SuspendLayout();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// tableLayout
// 
this.tableLayout.ColumnCount = 1;
this.tableLayout.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
this.tableLayout.Controls.Add(this.labelDate, 0, 0);
this.tableLayout.Controls.Add(this.labelTime, 0, 1);
this.tableLayout.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.tableLayout.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.tableLayout.Name = "tableLayout";
this.tableLayout.RowCount = 3;
this.tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 24F));
this.tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 24F));
this.tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
this.tableLayout.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
this.tableLayout.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// labelDate
// 
this.labelDate.AutoSize = true;
this.labelDate.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
this.labelDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(742, 0);
this.labelDate.Name = "labelDate";
this.labelDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 24);
this.labelDate.TabIndex = 0;
this.labelDate.Text = "26-8-2019";
// 
// labelTime
// 
this.labelTime.AutoSize = true;
this.labelTime.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
this.labelTime.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(748, 24);
this.labelTime.Name = "labelTime";
this.labelTime.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 24);
this.labelTime.TabIndex = 1;
this.labelTime.Text = "19:59:58";
```

Add whatever further content you want to the third row. Maybe add a panel to that row docked to "Fill"